# How do I format result of Excel formula to take currency format?

Tags: excel

I have 2 columns, each with a numeric value. The third column is the PRODUCT of the first 2 columns but it is just numbers. I want to in the format of `$xxxx.00` rather than `xxxx`.

What can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RIght click on the column header and choose Format Cells[image]

Answer (score 1):

Format the cell to currency. It's a command on the Home ribbon.

[image]

Comment: Your answer works as well however it looks like it is for Excel 2013 on Windows. I should specified I am using 2011 for OS X.

Comment: You should. In your question. Not in a comment.